# Two state switch/toggle - Should the "on"/"active" state be on the left or on the right?

Tags: gui-design, toggle

I recently looked for switch examples to figure out if the On/Active option should be on the left or the right.

In most cases, the switch is on the right when it shows the On/Active state. (that's what feels natural to me too)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But I saw examples for the opposite as well.

[image]
[image]

What do you think, which one makes more sense? Why?

Comment: In the past this was solved by having UP be ON with toggle switches on control panels. Then the UK decided to make their toggles look different...

Answer (score 2):

I'm my opinion this problem has no importance for end user.

[One research](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/03/150313130857.htm) suggest that people prefer left to right movement, and I guess that activating or turning something on can be considered progression or movement forward. Therefore, handle should be at the right side of the control in active state.